# Is this a valid proof that if an element $x$, is within the closure of a set $A$ (in a metric space) then $\exists (a_n) \in A : a_n \rightarrow x$

Tags: proof-verification, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

First form a sequence of epsilons $(\epsilon_n): \epsilon_1> \epsilon_2>\epsilon_3>\cdots$
    if $x \in \bar{A}$ then by the definition of the closure we have $$\forall \epsilon>0 , \exists a\in A :  d(x,a)< \epsilon$$
    Now for each $\epsilon_n$ there exists an $a_n$ such that $d(x,a_n)< \epsilon_n$ hence $$d(x,a_n)< \epsilon_n <\epsilon_{n-1}<\cdots< \epsilon_1 $$
    as constructed.

So we have $$\forall \epsilon_1>0 , \exists N \in \text{the natural numbers}:  d(x,a_n)< \epsilon_1,  \forall n>N$$

and so $a_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

(N.B Since this list can be constructed regardless of the magnitude of $\epsilon_1$ we really are free to choose any $\epsilon_1$ we like, as long as it is positive.)

EDIT: Thanks for your answers, I'd up vote you all but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Is the $\epsilon_1$ in the last statement the same as the first term of your epsilon sequence? If so, you can't write $(\forall \epsilon_1)$ because $\epsilon_1$ has already been defined. If not, how do you know the last statement holds?

Comment: Both epsilons are the same yes, it's been defined in the sense that it is arbitrarily greater than 0 but all epsilons we could consider are also greater than 0?

Comment: In you task you have to first pick the sequence $a_n$, then fix an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and proceed with the definition of convergence. $a_n$ can not depend on $\epsilon$. Of course, you can first define an auxillary sequence of epsilons to construct $a_n$, but when you later fix the arbitrary $\epsilon$, you can't assume it's in whatever relation to the sequence you defined.

Comment: @Adayah I see what you are saying, thank you for feed-back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is what is needed. However, imagine that you take $\varepsilon_n=1+\dfrac{1}{n}$. We still have $\varepsilon_1>\varepsilon_2>\dots$, but nothing ensures that $d(x,a_n)\to 0$. So you need to ensure that $\varepsilon_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. A classical choice is $\varepsilon_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$.

In the proof you don't need to go back to $\varepsilon_1$. You have $$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,d(x,a_n)\le\varepsilon_n.$$

Hence, as $\varepsilon_n\to 0$, you can conclude that $x=\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n$ as desired.

A final remark: this is generally not mentioned in proofs, but when you have

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists a_n\in A,d(x,a)\le\varepsilon_n$$

still this is not rigorous enough to justify the existence of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. The justification is the axiom of choice.

**Edit**

The existence of such a sequence can be justified using the axiom of choice. There are many different equivalent forms of this axiom. The one that I find most "natural" for our purpose is the following:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a nonempty collection of nonempty sets. Then there exists a function $f$ (called a [choice function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function)) such that
> $$\forall S\in\mathcal{C},f(S)\in S.$$

In other words, the image by $f$ of a set $S\in\mathcal{C}$ is an element "chosen" from $S$.

We can now justify the existence of your sequence. Remember that a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $X$ is a function $a:\mathbb{N}\to X$, and writing $a_n$ instead of $a(n)$. The key is:

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists a\in A,d(x,a)\le\varepsilon_n.$$

So, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $S_n=\{a\in A\mid d(x,a)\le\varepsilon_n\}$, which is nonempty by what's above, and let $\mathcal{C}=\{S_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $f:\mathcal{C}\to X$ be the corresponding choice function. Then the sequence $a_n=f(S_n)$ satisfies

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},d(x,a_n)\le\varepsilon_n.$$

Remark: This kind of construction of sequences oftently used in proofs in textbooks without even mentioning the axiom of choice. So I guess you shouldn't feel obliged to always mention it, but it's important to know how it's used.

Comment: Not very important: the sequence $\varepsilon_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ is increasing.

Comment: Maybe you meant $1+\dfrac 1 n \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it possible to get a little more detail on exactly how one would utilize the axiom of choice to infer the existence of such a sequence? I feel this is the part that I'm struggling to understand, the existence of the sequence.

Comment: @valcofadden You're welcome. Sure! I will edit my answer soon to include that part.

Comment: @Adayah Thank you. Corrected it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes thanks. Corrected it.

Comment: To me the demonstration of usage of the axiom of choice seems out of place here. It's like you're going all the way down to that axiom to justify one particular element while keeping the rest of the proof at usual naive set theory standard. One might as well ask why the family $\mathcal{C}$ exists, and you would have to use the axiom of comprehension. But sure, if OP's interested, why not.

Comment: @Adayah Yes you're right, and that's I said "This kind of construction of sequences oftently used in proofs in textbooks without even mentioning the axiom of choice." I just felt, however, that it is interesting to know it. That's why I tried to tease his curiosity.

Comment: @Scientifica Thank you very much, your response clears up the problems I was having with the standard proof of the result, that is how you can justify sequences like the one above. Many thanks!

Comment: @valcofadden You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

It's not enough to say $\varepsilon_1 > \varepsilon_2>\varepsilon_3 > \cdots.$ You also need to say $\lim\limits_{n\,\to\,\infty} \varepsilon_n =0.$

For example, if $\varepsilon_1 = 1.1$ and $\varepsilon_2=1.01$ and $\varepsilon_3 = 1.001$ and so on, then you do have $\varepsilon_1 > \varepsilon_2>\varepsilon_3 > \cdots$ but you do not have $\lim\limits_{n\,\to\,\infty} \varepsilon_n =0,$ so that will not serve.

I would start with $\varepsilon_n = \dfrac 1 n$ or some other specific sequence whose terms decrease and approach $0,$ and after that proceed as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Given $\epsilon_1>0,$ the problem is how to construct the sequence $(\epsilon_n) $ such that
$$\epsilon_1>\epsilon_2>\cdots>\epsilon_n $$

You can take for example
$$\epsilon_n=\frac {\epsilon_1}{n} $$

then
$$d (x,a_n)<\frac {\epsilon_1}{n} $$

and squeeze.

Comment: How do you define $\epsilon_1$ ?

Comment: @Adayah It is given >0 arbitrary.

Comment: Given by what? I mean I hope you don't take it from the definition of a limit, since it would be wrong.

Comment: @Adayah by you for example.